# launch `onicecandidate` event after getting answer

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I faced a very strange behavior WebRTC in Chrome browser. I use simple code like this :

```
peerConn.onicecandidate = function (event) {
    if (event.candidate) {
        let candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate) 
        // Send the -candidate -  to the remote peer
        } else {
    console.log('all candidates are set');
    }
 }
```

and this :

```
function obtainCandidatesFromSignalServer (){
     console.log('obtain candidates ...');
     peerConn.addIceCandidate(candidate);
 }
```

I expect the event to be called after peer A and peer B exchange `offer` and  `answer`, but this is not so. When I just send `offer` from A to B triggered `onicecandidate` event but till peer B not send  `answer` the obtainCandidatesFromSignalServer function will fail. So, how can I call the `onicecandidate` function only after `offer`-`answer` exchange ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect the event to be called after peer A and peer B exchange offer and answer, but this is not so.

That expectation is incorrect. The whole point of Trickle ICE is to speed up negotiation, so offerer candidates chase the offer immediately, and reversely, answerer candidates chase the answer.

In other words, what you'll see on your signaling channel one way is:

```
offer candidate candidate candidate
```

...and the same going the other way:

```
answer candidate candidate candidate
```

Think of them as updates to the description that was sent. In fact, if you were to wait a few seconds before sending `pc.localDescription` then the description will already contain all the candidates, and you don't need to trickle them. Trickle ICE is an optimization, since time to connect is usually critical.

Comment: both peers must send icecandidate each other?

Comment: and `onicecandidate` event start while creating `offer` or `answer`, isn't?

Comment: ICE gathering starts after the *setLocalDescription* success callback.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting ? I never had to set `onicecandidate` at a specific time.

I suspect the error is something else : why are you creating a `new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate)` when `event.candidate` is already an instance of RtcIceCandidate (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent/candidate) ? I guess when calling new RtcIceCandidate, you are creating an invalid candidate and sending that to the other peer, thus the error.

Comment: no errors. but icecandidates are send only Caller,  Callee send just  answer. Strange, because `peerConn` ise singl `RTCPeerConnection` object on client side.